# Dask & Geopandas: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: dask, geopandas

I have a GeoSeries with a shapely Polygon object in each cell, and I am trying to parallelize rasterization of all the features (and I am trying to get a Series of 2d-arrays in the end, which I then convert into xarray.DF):

```
cbd = dd.from_pandas(cb['geometry'], npartitions=2)

def _rasterize_area(geom):
    F = features.rasterize([(geom, geom.area)],
                             out_shape= (cvs.plot_height, 
                             cvs.plot_width), transform=aform, dtype=float64)
    return F

A = cbd.apply(_rasterize_area, convert_dtype=False)
```

However when I run the last line above, I get an error:

```
<ipython-input-18-f1e938162097> in _rasterize_area(geom)
      1 def _rasterize_area(geom):
----> 2     F = features.rasterize([(geom, geom.area)],  out_shape=(cvs.plot_height, cvs.plot_width), transform=aform, dtype=float64)
      3     return F

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'area'
```

(this is just the meaningful part of the error message)

Not sure where and how my objects were converted to string, though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask dataframes don't officially support non-Pandas dataframes.  I wouldn't be surprised if at some point your dataframes were converted into Pandas dataframes and that forced some sort of string conversion.

There is a highly-experimental dask-geopandas implementation available here: https://github.com/mrocklin/dask-geopandas

You might also want to consider the Cython branch of GeoPandas, which can be much faster without the burdens of parallelism.

Comment: Thanks!
I firmly believe that the bottleneck is not in the geopandas itself, but in the way rasterio's rasterization works; Do you think I'd have a better chance with dask.Bags, given this is embarrassingly parallel task?

Comment: Perhaps.  I don't know enough about the operation to be able to make concrete recommendations.  In your situation I would try things out, profile, and see how it goes.